# How come this function isn't reassigning the variable?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am doing a simple javascript problem where I have to pass an array through a function and have the array reassigned a different value. How come when I pass through an array (or even any variable) I have to specifically reassign the array in order for it to change? Can't I just use the code in the function to use the parameter to do that for me? Here's my code:

```
<script>
var str = 'this is my sentence';
//Write a function called reverse that takes is given str as it's only argument and returns that string after it's been reversed

function reverse(x) {
    x = x.split('').reverse().join('');
    return x;
}

//returns with the text reversed, but str is still 'this is my sentence' and not the reversed version
</script>
```

Comment: Where are you calling the reverse function?

Comment: I see a definition of reverse(), but where do you invoke it and store the result in str?

Comment: "Can't I just use the code in the function to use the parameter to do that for me?" - nope. Parameters don't work that way; you can't reassign the caller's variables through a function's arguments.

Comment: This may be helpful to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language

Comment: See [Is JavaScript a pass-by-reference or pass-by-value language?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language) for a more general explanation.

Comment: Also look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28148196/how-do-i-get-this-this-in-prototype-working/28148255#28148255

Answer (score 1):

You have to actually call the reverse function.  Your code works once you add `str = reverse(str);`

```
<script>
var str = 'this is my sentence';
//Write a function called reverse that takes is given str as it's only argument and returns that string after it's been reversed

function reverse(x) {
    x = x.split('').reverse().join('');
    return x;
}

str = reverse(str);  //Call the function

window.alert(str);  //show an alert box to view reversed string

</script>
```

**EDIT**

It seems the brunt of his question is `[Why do] I have to specifically reassign the array in order for it to change?`.

The argument is a primitive and with primitives, javascript **passes by value**. Meaning that the called functions' parameter will be a **copy** of the callers' passed argument.  It is not the same item.

The alternative would be **pass by reference** in which case the called functions' parameter will be the same object as the caller's passed argument.  In this case, changes occurring inside the function on the object passed as a parameter will be 'available' outside the function - because it's the same object.  This is how Javascript passes objects.

In Javascript, a string can be either an object or a primitive depending on how you create it:

`var str = "I'm a String primitive";` //This is a primitive

`var str = new String("I'm a String object");` //this is an object