# String prototype changing the string value

Tags: javascript, string, prototype

I'm trying to change the string value inside its protoype function:

```
String.prototype.myfunction=function(){
    this += "a";
    return this;
};
```

But as it seems I just can't change the value. If I try to run that on the console I just get the error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment`

Is it possible to change the strings value?
Thanks in advance

Comment: See also [how do i get “this = this” in prototype working](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28148196/1048572) or [Assign object to “this”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15598549/assign-object-to-this)

Answer (score 3):

I think it has to do with the immutability of strings and the fact that `this` is a constant.

It works just fine if your example is trivially changed to:

```
String.prototype.myfunction=function(){
    return this + 'a';
};
```

Comment: What I actually wanted was to change its value, I know returning this+"a" works fine. Anyway, thanks for the help

Comment: Treat strings in JavaScript as immutable. Work with the object returned from the function instead.

Answer (score 0):

Strings are immutable. You may want to use an array of characters instead:

```js
class MyString extends Array {
  constructor(str) {
    super(...String(str));
  }
  myfunction() {
    this.push("a");
    return this;
  }
  toString() {
    return this.join('');
  }
}
var s = new MyString("hello!");
s.myfunction();
console.log(s + '');
```