# How to change the value of String from String.prototype?

Tags: javascript, node.js, string

I wrote this code:

```js
String.prototype.toJadenCase = function () {
  return this.split(/\s/).map(word => word[0].toUpperCase() + word.substr(1)).join(' ')
}

let text = 'hello world'
text.toJadenCase()
alert(text) // hello world
```

And it doesn't change the value of string, from that function called is.
As I saw here: [String prototype changing the string value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40710046/string-prototype-changing-the-string-value) , it should work, but it doesn't

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Since String.prototype.toJadenCase() returns a value and does not change the original string, text.toJadenCase() does nothing. Instead, use `text = text.toJadenCase()` or something similar.

Comment: I *highly* recommend you avoid assigning protoype properties with the `=` operator. Instead use `Object.defineProperty(String.prototype, 'toJadenCase', { value: function() { /* ... */ }, enumerable: false });`. This avoids polluting enumeration with `for ... in` loops.

Comment: @Gershom - Although to be fair, `for-in` on strings is a fairly dodgy thing to do. ;-) (But you're right about using `defineProperty`. Typically you'd make it writable and configurable, not enumerable. [They all default to false.])

Comment: That's right @T.J.Crowder! I want to endorse `Object.defineProperty` without endorsing string `for-in` :-P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **can't** change the value of a string, strings are immutable. All you can do is create a *new* string and return it:

```
    text = text.toJadenCase()
//  ^^^^^^^
```

```js
String.prototype.toJadenCase = function () {
  return this.split(/\s/).map(word => word[0].toUpperCase() + word.substr(1)).join(' ')
}

let text = 'hello world'
text = text.toJadenCase()
alert(text) // hello world
```

---

Side note: It's less important with `String.prototype` than with some others, but best practice is to define anything you add to the built-in prototypes (if you add anything to them at all) as *non-enumerable*, which is the default when you use `Object.defineProperty`:

```
Object.defineProperty(String.prototype, "toJadenCase", {
    value: function () {
        return this.split(/\s/).map(word => word[0].toUpperCase() + word.substr(1)).join(' ');
    },
    writable: true,
    configurable: true
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `text.toJadenCase()` to `let text = 'hello world'.toJadenCase()`

```js
String.prototype.toJadenCase = function() {
  return this.split(/\s/).map(word => word[0].toUpperCase() + word.substr(1)).join(' ')
}

let text = 'hello world'.toJadenCase()
console.log(text)
```